# Core Plot: Axis titles show randomly, not always working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-plot

I am trying to get my X and Y axis titles to show, but it seems they are not always working:

```
CPXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
    CPXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPDecimalFromFloat(min);
    x.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance %@", distLabel];
    x.titleLocation = CPDecimalFromFloat(7.5f);
    x.titleOffset = 55.0f;

    CPXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPDecimalFromFloat(minDist);
    y.title = @"Altitude";
    y.titleOffset = 95.0f;
    y.titleLocation = CPDecimalFromFloat(150.0f);
```

Sometimes the X title will show, but the Y axis title NEVER shows.  Why are they not showing?  Is it the padding?

```
plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft = 50;
    plotAreaFrame.paddingTop = 10;
    plotAreaFrame.paddingRight = 20;
    plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 50;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase your bottom and left padding. Your title offsets are more than that on both axes so the titles are hidden.

Comment: Ok, I can see them now.  But their position still varies based on the data that I load into my graph.  Why would they move around on different graphs?

Comment: The titleLocation is given in data coordinates so the title will move relative to the graph if you change the corresponding plot space range. If you don't set the titleLocation (i.e., leave it at the default value of NAN), it will center the title in the plot space range.